# how to remove space from the xpath node after execution?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, web-scraping

Sorry, if I posted a weird question. Now, I am explaining it properly.

I am trying to scrap a data from a web page say for example from: http://www.koolkart.com/nokia-lumia-800-p8251

I am trying to get price of the device listed in the table near "saholic" it is "Rs. 17759/-" and xpath to it is `"//*[@id="price-chart"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]"`

Now, when I execute the xpath in chrome, it gives the price with space

```
"

                                Rs. 17759/-
                                "
```

Now, when I execute it in php

```
<?php
$xpath = '//*[@id="price-chart"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]';          
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTMLFile('http://www.koolkart.com/nokia-lumia-800-p8251');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($html);   
if (!$xml) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}
echo $xml;
$source_image = $xml->xpath($xpath);
print_r($source_image);
?>
```

it gives error !

So, is there any solution how to remove those trailing spaces or any other way how to get that price?

Comment: I'd vote to ditch the XML parsers, and just use a regular expression, especially if the XML you're getting is badly formatted / causing you problems.

Comment: the xpath you tried in the browser and the one in your script aren't the same.

Comment: @katsuo11 sorry it was mistake in posting the question. i have edited it. And its the same stuff. trailing spaces appear in browser and wen i try with php it shows error. When i try to get the name of the product via //*[@id="prod-container-block"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/h1 it works in browser (gives result without trailing space) and it also works in the script !

Comment: @VivekSancheti Tried your code, it returns the SimpleXMLElement Object with the text "wifi :"

Comment: @katsuo11 ohhh whts happening with me i deleted the wrong query ry the right query is "//*[@id="price-chart"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]" and the wifi is working in script. but this one is only working in browser not in script. please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you want the price then.

You don't get the same results in the browser and your script because the `tbody` tag is added by your browser, but isn't part of the source.

You can use an expression like this :

```
'//*[@id="price-chart"]/tr[1]/td[3]'
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked out. Can i know what changes you did ? I face same trailing space problem in many website. Any generalized solution ?

Comment: @VivekSancheti I just removed the /tbody part of your expression as I already explained. For your trailing spaces problems, try `echo (string) trim($source_image[0]);`

Comment: really thanks :) I spent a lot and lot time to find solution and you gave it.